# What software/hardware is needed to receive (and respond to) SMS from multiple machines?

Tags: sms, gsm, sms-gateway

What software/hardware do the SMS centers use to make the following possible:
An SMS is received to a number. The SMS is routed to one of X machines (Mac/PC). An operator responds to the sender.

It seems that a GSM modem is needed?  However, I have trouble understanding the architecture.

Is there any plug-and-play solution? Are there any specific frameworks/languages/tools for building such a system? How do you route incoming messages to machines? How do you queue outgoing text messages?

Answer (score 2):

For getting SMS there are at least 2 types of numbers exist: real (simcards) and virtual (VLN).

Real numbers:

-simcards you need to own and to insert into devices called gsm-gateways or gsm-modems, gsm-modem pools etc. These devices are like collection of many mobile phones, they will collect and/or keep/forward all incoming SMS (to some DB, to server/script etc.)

-to make lot of users manage SMS you need some tool. Most common - webserver with appropriate GUI software. Webserver collects all SMS into DB (by downloading them from gsm-gateways via protocols like SMPP or HTTP, or by geting as HTTP Requests from devices). Via some WEB-GUI you can make messages available to your operators for replying.

Virtual numbers (VLN) (provided by most SMS operators):

-no need for hardware. Just contract operator for numbers, then connect via HTTP API or some protocol like SMPP for collecting inbound SMS on these numbers, or get them on your server as HTTP Requests from operator's server.

-WEB-GUI the same as for real numbers

So basically the flow is:

for Real numbers: SMS Origination from phone -> GSM-operator (Vodaf... etc) -> SIM-Card (Vodaf...) in GSM-gateway -> GSM-Gateway API -> Your Web-GUI

for Virtual numbers: SMS Origination from phone -> GSM-operator (Vodaf... etc) -> SMS Service provider (Clicat... etc.) API -> Your Web-GUI

There are some software titles free and paid available for each task.

Answer (score 0):

Any organisation with a large amount of traffic will most likely use a connection to an opertors SMSC (SMS Message Centre in an operators network) via an IP interface and the SMPP protocol.

The SMPP protocol is an open standard designed to bridge the IP web world to the CCITT No.7 messaging world in the telcos, and allow web services be built to send an receive SMS's.

There are also providers who provide aggregation services for SMS - some are independent and some are 'preferred partners' of an operator (e.g. http://developer.att.com/technical-library/app-certification-policies/working-with-aggregators)